# How to insert a new line or enter in Microsoft Word references style (XSL file)

Tags: xslt, reference, ms-word, newline

I have prepared a modified references style for Microsoft word 2010 document. Following part of XSL file indicates how online resources should be displayed in the references list at the end of my word document.

```
<source type="DocumentFromInternetSite">
  <column id="1">
    <halign>right</halign>
    <valign>top</valign>
    <format>{[%RefOrder%]}</format>
  </column>
  <column id="2">
    <halign>left</halign>
    <valign>top</valign>
    <format>{%Author:1%, }{%InternetSiteTitle|Title%,}{ %URL:l%}{ Published %Year%.}{ Retreived %Month%.}</format>
  </column>
  <sortkey></sortkey>
</source>
```

My aim is to have a **new line** or **enter** character in the format tag just before `{ Published %Year%.}{ Retreived %Month%.}` in order to have the mentioned information in the next line. I tried to use `&#xa;` or `&#10;`, but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: I have no idea why XSL will be changed to XSLT in the tags when I published or edit the above post.

Comment: [tag:xsl] and [tag:xslt] are synonyms, that's why the former is remapped to the latter. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/synonyms

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the combination CR+LF,

```
&#13;&#10;
```

for a line break.

Comment: Tried and added in the above format tag, but unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br></br>` in desired location

Comment: That would make the XML invalid.